# Bluetooth can receive data but cannot transmit it (socket programming in C++ to communicate Matlab)

Tags: c++, linux, matlab, sockets, bluetooth

I am using Raspberry Pi 3's internal bluetooth and I am writing a c++ code to connect the bluetooth of my windows PC. On the PC side, I use Matlab and I am able to send bytes to raspberry. However when I try to send bytes from raspberry to PC, I get the following error:

"Transport endpoint is not connected"

and Matlab says "Unsuccessful read: the specified amount of data was not returned within the timeout period".

Another interesting thing is that, when I try to send more than three bytes from Matlab, raspberry only receives the first three as if the rest did not exist. If I use two reads in a row, I am able to get 6 bytes and so on. Just pointing this odd fact since I thought it might be connected with my main problem and be a clue.

I have also tried to send a file manually, using the bluetooth symbol on menubar and it worked. So c++ code should be doing something different to cause this problem.

What is likely to be the cause of my problem? How can I send data from raspberry to my computer using c++?

My code is as follows:
(Referred website: http://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/index.html)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>
#include <bluetooth/rfcomm.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
struct sockaddr_rc loc_addr = { 0 }, rem_addr = { 0 };
char buf[1024] = { 0 };
int s, client, bytes_read;
socklen_t opt = sizeof(rem_addr);

// allocate socket
s = socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTPROTO_RFCOMM);

bdaddr_t tempBDADDR = {0};
// bind socket to port 1 of the first available 
// local bluetooth adapter
loc_addr.rc_family = AF_BLUETOOTH;
loc_addr.rc_bdaddr = tempBDADDR;
loc_addr.rc_channel = (uint8_t) 1;
bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&loc_addr, sizeof(loc_addr));

// put socket into listening mode
listen(s, 1);

// accept one connection
client = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&rem_addr, &opt);

ba2str( &rem_addr.rc_bdaddr, buf );
fprintf(stderr, "accepted connection from %s\n", buf);
memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));

// read data from the client
bytes_read = read(client, buf, sizeof(buf));
if( bytes_read > 0 ) {
    printf("received [%s]\n", buf);
}

int status = 0;
// send a message
if( status == 0 ) {
    status = write(s, "hello!", 6);
}

if( status < 0 ) perror("uh oh");

// close connection
close(client);
close(s);
return 0;
}
```

Matlab side is as straight forward as:

```
b = Bluetooth('raspberrypi', 1);
fopen(b);
fwrite(b, uint('1234'));
input = fread(b,6)
fclose(b);
clear('b');
```

EDIT:

Just figured that I do not get the "Transport endpoint is not connected" when I use the following line. However this only allows me to connect as client, whereas matlab only has a client type of connection. So now, I am able to send data to my computer from another socket without getting any errors, but cannot read it with matlab.

```
status = connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out. Leaving this here in case it helps someone else as well.

When a connection is accepted, a new descriptor is returned (along with a new socket). This is a significant difference from connect(). So I was wrong at the following line.

```
status = write(s, "hello!", 6);
```

changing it to

```
status = write(client, "hello!", 6);
```

worked like a charm.

(Reference: http://users.pja.edu.pl/~jms/qnx/help/tcpip_4.25_en/prog_guide/sock_advanced_tut.html)